# Insert and delete rows in UITableView before first appearance on screen

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I perform a bunch of row/section inserts and deletions with `insertSections`, `insertRows`, `deleteRows` etc. during the startup of a view controller. The manipulations are triggered by events of a background process (of course the actual calls to the table view are performed on the main thread; also, they are wrapped in `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`).

- When I start off these row manipulations in `viewWillAppear` I eventually get a crash because of an inconsistency in the row data: `attempt to delete row 1 from section 0 which only contains 1 rows before the update`. When this happens, there actually are 2 rows in the section before the update which apparently is not correctly recognized  by the table view.
- However, when I start the exactly same sequence of manipulations in `viewDidAppear`, there's no crash and the rows animate in and out as expected.

This looks like the table view has problems with a fast-running sequence of inserts and deletes before it appears. Is this a known limitation, or do you have another explanation for this issue?

Comment: Why bother updating the view if it's not onscreen? Just update the data source.

Comment: To Josh's point, what's displayed on the screen should reflect the data.  The easiest and most performant strategy (generally speaking) is to update your data source and then invoke the reload function (which will invoke the various dataSource/delegate UITableView functions).  You could be prepping the data in the view controller's initializer or anyplace prior to viewDidAppear if you want this ready to go ahead of time.

Comment: @JoshCaswell My question is about whether the insert/delete APIs are usable for an offscreen table view, not whether that's a good idea. The code performing these animations is framework code, not specific to a single VC, so I'd like it to be as flexible as possible which includes using it with a table view that's just appearing on screen. If this is not supported by Cocoa I can limit the framework code's use accordingly; if in general performing these operations should work for offline table views as well, I have a framework bug.

Comment: I would hope that Cocoa would be well-written enough to be resilient in the situation you're describing, so personally I would suspect my code first. It might be worth asking about this on the Apple Dev forums; someone from DTS could have useful input.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Good point, I'll try my luck there unless I get another answer in the next few days...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you dont need to manipulate actual UITableViewCells, you may just manipulate some kind of view models (plain objects), prepare them, and then reload UITableView with them on viewWillAppear

Comment: Actually, that's what I do: I have a view model backing the table view, and it's the view model which drives the inserts and deletes I mentioned.